# How recent is ViewsRecentUniqueUsers?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property

In SharePoint Online I want to show the top 5 most popular pages. I can do this by sorting my search results by the default managed property 'ViewsRecentUniqueUsers'. This works fine! But can someone tell me how recent these views actually are? 30 days? 7 days? 1 day? I can't find any documentation about this...

Answer (score 2):

As per [this article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/View-Popularity-Trends-and-Most-Popular-Items-a522cc35-4e63-49da-9968-85c588878932?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB#) on Office Support, `ViewsRecentUniqueUsers` is

> "Recent (views the last 14 days)"